# Error: Debug Failure. Output generation failed when running formatjs extract

Tags: formatjs

When running formatjs extract this is what we got. From the stack trace it seems that the issue is from formatjs themselves. Feel like I am stuck on what the issue is here.

```
$ formatjs extract './src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --out-file './src/i18n/messages/messages.json' --extract-from-format-message-call --throws
Error: Debug Failure. Output generation failed
    at Object.transpileModule (/Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:126894:29)
    at processFile (/Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/src/extract.js:104:39)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/src/extract.js:163:59
    at step (/Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/src/extract.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/src/extract.js:25:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/.../node_modules/@formatjs/cli/src/extract.js:16:58)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be processing a file that needs to be ignored using `--ignore`. Can you upgrade to the latest version and re-run your command? Long added the filename in this commit https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/commit/ceb0bf8a58c13fe6811bc35191018ee1c431484a

Reference: https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/2044